# 404 (Not Found) when attempting to POST information to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a React Application that has an express backend. I am attempting to make a fetch from my front end to my backend. This fetch is a login, where I pass in various credentials checking my clearDB to see if a user is legitimate or not. For some reason I am receiving a 404 not found. The good news is that 404 means that my backend and frontend are communicating well, but the bad new is that it cannot access the route properly. I have provided some files here. Please let me know if you need any additional files. As always, I appreciate your support and look forward to this discussion.

Folder Structure:

```
DemoApp
  >bin
  >classes
  >client
    ->build
    ->node_modules
    ->public
    ->public
    ->src
    ->package.json
    ->static.json
  >Design
  >node_modules
  >public
  >routes
    ->api.js
  >views
  app.js
  package.json
```

**Console Logs:**

```
Login.js:69 POST https://<hostname>.herokuapp.com/api/login 404 (Not Found)
```

**app.js(NodeJS backend):**

```
...
const corsOptions = {
   origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
   credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

**package.json(Located in client folder):**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "password-validator": "^5.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**static.json**

```
{
  "root": "build/",
   "routes": {
    "/assets/*": "/assets/",
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

**Login.js(REACT Component):**

```
const url = '/api/login'

fetch(url, {
 method: 'POST',
 credentials: 'include',
 headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 body: JSON.stringify(user)
 })
```

**api.js(NodeJS backend route)**

```
   .
   .
   .

    var connection = mysql.createPool('mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<database name>?reconnect=true')
    router.post('/login', function(req,response,next) {
        const query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = TRIM(?)"
        connection.query(query1, [req.body.username], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                response.json({'message': 'Incorrect Username/Password', 'status': 0})
            } else {
                req.session.username = req.body.username
                response.json({'message': 'You have successfully logged in', 'status': 1})
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are declaring a router in another file different from app.js, you should tell your app to use that router.

So, if you have a file like loginRouter.js, with something like:

```
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/api/login', auth, (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(<whatever>);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, in app.js, you have to import it

```
const loginRouter = require('./routers/login');
```

and apply it to the app.js with the .use method like this:

```
app.use(loginRouter);
```

Hope that is the only thing why you cant access that endpoint from your frontend!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am receiving the same error on my end. Is there any other files that I can share with you or can we speak in real time via some other application(discord, google duo, zoom, etc..) @Maximiliano Poggio

Comment: I will upvote this, because adding: app.use(loginRouter) would be necessary as you have suggested given the use case. In addition, the proxy will be necessary for the React to communicate with the backend for non static assets as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the React Front end to communicate with the Express backend, I had to configure the Proxy. I opened up React's package.json and added the “proxy” line like this:

```
{
  "name": "bible-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9000",
. 
.
.
}
```

The port (9000) in the “proxy” line must match the port that your Express server is running on. Thus any time the React app makes a request to something that’s not a static asset (not an image or CSS or index.html, basically), it will forward the request to the server specified in "proxy".

Source: https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/